# How can I get the post id from within functions.php

Tags: functions

I'm building a function within functions.php

Within my function I want to make use of the post id of current post.
How do I do this?

The last thing I tried was this:

```
global $post ;
$id = $post->id ;
```

However, this returns an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on where you have placed your hook. If you hook after 'wp' then you should be able to access the global $post object just fine.

Before that, the object has not been initialized and thus its not accessible.

You could hook into the template_redirect as follows.

```
add_action('template_redirect', function() {

   $post_id = get_queried_object_id();

});
```

Comment: which hooks might be appropriate?

Comment: @bob I updated my answer with an example that should work from the functions.php file

Answer (score 2):

You can call "id" but object call as "ID"
Please Replace with this code

```
global $post ;
$id = $post->ID ;
```

Comment: Yes, this is likely because the in the question the `id` is lowercase. Try this and it should work for you @bob.